# Manual Insertion of node in JTree on specific row

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtree

I am using the DynamicTree and DynamicTreeDemo class from docs.oracle.com tutorials. The given example allow to add child node dynamically on selected node.

I have modified the

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(Object child)
```

function for changing TreePath. That is i have fixed the tree path so that whenever i will click the Add button it will add child node only to that path.

```
    Object[] o = { new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node"), new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent 2"),
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 2") };

    parentPath = new TreePath(o);
```

But after my modification the add button is not working. How can i solve this problem so that i can add node by changing the path in code?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;

public class DynamicTree extends JPanel {
protected DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
protected DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
protected JTree tree;
private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

public DynamicTree() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node");
    treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
    treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new MyTreeModelListener());
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.setEditable(true);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    add(scrollPane);
}

/** Remove all nodes except the root node. */
public void clear() {
    rootNode.removeAllChildren();
    treeModel.reload();
}

/** Remove the currently selected node. */
public void removeCurrentNode() {
    TreePath currentSelection = tree.getSelectionPath();
    if (currentSelection != null) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (currentSelection.getLastPathComponent());
        MutableTreeNode parent = (MutableTreeNode) (currentNode.getParent());
        if (parent != null) {
            treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Either there was no selection, or the root was selected.
    toolkit.beep();
}

/** Add child to the currently selected node. */
public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(Object child) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = null;
    TreePath parentPath = tree.getSelectionPath();

    //////////////////////////// Modification for fixing place /////////////    

    Object[] o = { new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node"), new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent 2"),
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 2") };

    parentPath = new TreePath(o);

    //////////////////////////// end of modification///////////////////////


    if (parentPath == null) {
        parentNode = rootNode;
    } else {
        parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (parentPath.getLastPathComponent());
    }

    return addObject(parentNode, child, true);
}

public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child) {
    return addObject(parent, child, false);
}

public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child, boolean shouldBeVisible) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child);

    if (parent == null) {
        parent = rootNode;
    }

    // It is key to invoke this on the TreeModel, and NOT DefaultMutableTreeNode
    treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());

    // Make sure the user can see the lovely new node.
    if (shouldBeVisible) {
        tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
    }
    return childNode;
}

class MyTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {
    public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());

        /*
         * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the node
         * we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the specified node are
         * the same.
         */

        int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));

        System.out.println("The user has finished editing the node.");
        System.out.println("New value: " + node.getUserObject());
    }

    public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
    }

    public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
    }

    public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
    }
}
}





import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class DynamicTreeDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private int newNodeSuffix = 1;
private static String ADD_COMMAND = "add";
private static String REMOVE_COMMAND = "remove";
private static String CLEAR_COMMAND = "clear";

private DynamicTree treePanel;

public DynamicTreeDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    // Create the components.
    treePanel = new DynamicTree();
    populateTree(treePanel);

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.setActionCommand(ADD_COMMAND);
    addButton.addActionListener(this);

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    removeButton.setActionCommand(REMOVE_COMMAND);
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setActionCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);

    // Lay everything out.
    treePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    add(treePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    panel.add(addButton);
    panel.add(removeButton);
    panel.add(clearButton);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void populateTree(DynamicTree treePanel) {
    String p1Name = new String("Parent 1");
    String p2Name = new String("Parent 2");
    String c1Name = new String("Child 1");
    String c2Name = new String("Child 2");

    DefaultMutableTreeNode p1, p2;

    p1 = treePanel.addObject(null, p1Name);
    p2 = treePanel.addObject(null, p2Name);

    treePanel.addObject(p1, c1Name);
    treePanel.addObject(p1, c2Name);

    treePanel.addObject(p2, c1Name);
    treePanel.addObject(p2, c2Name);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if (ADD_COMMAND.equals(command)) {
        // Add button clicked
        treePanel.addObject("New Node " + newNodeSuffix++);
    } else if (REMOVE_COMMAND.equals(command)) {
        // Remove button clicked
        treePanel.removeCurrentNode();
    } else if (CLEAR_COMMAND.equals(command)) {
        // Clear button clicked.
        treePanel.clear();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be invoked
 * from the event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTreeDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    DynamicTreeDemo newContentPane = new DynamicTreeDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    // creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modification you made is not correct because by creating some new `DefaultMutableTreeNode`s with the same name as the existing nodes the new `TreePath` would not be the same `TreePath` object. Their references are not the same. Then simply this new path you are creating can not be found in the `TreeModel` and the result you see is nothing happening.

You should get the path for inserting new nodes from the `TreeModel` itself. For example if you want to add a new child to the **Child 2** you can get its reference like this:

```
// ////////////////////////// Modification for fixing place // /////////////

Object[] o = { rootNode.getLastLeaf() }; // For you testing purposes 
                                         // this will return the Child 2" reference, 
                                         // next time it will return "New Node 2" and so on.

parentPath = new TreePath(o);

// ////////////////////////// end of modification///////////////////////
```

If you want to add a new node at a specific location, you should get a reference to an existing node in the `TreeModel` not a new on the fly `TreeNode` which does not currently exists in the `TreeModel`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried this way before and it works. but i want to insert node in a specific path which i will write in my code. For example i wrote in the above code "Root Node/Paren 2/ Child 2". This path will be different in different click. I am stuck here to change the treepath instead of using "tree.getSelectionPath()". I don't know how can i do this.

Comment: I don't know your logic of adding new nodes to the tree, but the important note is to find that path from the `TreeModel` itself not by creating new `TreeNode` references in the memory. As I stated before creating `new DefaultMutableTreeNode` with the same name doesn't make a reference to existing nodes it the treeModel. If you have custom logic of adding new nodes to the tree, you should somehow traverse the treeModel starting from `rootNode` or `selectedNode` to find that specific node as the parent of your new node.